# Intel AX201 wifi adapter disconnecting frequently

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi, 22.10

I'm new to linux, so sorry for my little knowledge in advance.
Intel AX201 wifi adapter doesn't seem to work properly for me on Ubuntu 22.10. It didn't work so good with windows 10/11 too. Disconnects randomly and I can't get it working again; but when I reboot,it sometimes works for 10 minutes or so and then goes away again.
what info should I provide to be able to get any help?

Comment: If it "didn't work so good with windows 10/11 too", then it is not an OS  problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for quick reply! I've read online that many people have(mostly driver-related) issues with these Intel cards. but I wanna know if it can be solved -or at least find what the problem is- .

Comment: People had problems with older releases of Ubuntu where there were no drivers for this device.

Comment: @Pilot6 so you mean it's a hardware problem? If yes,how could I check that? Also It's a new laptop.

Comment: It can be a hardware problem, or it can be a problem with the AP compatibility. And "doesn't seem to work properly" is not informative.

Comment: @Pilot6 I can connect without problems using a usb adapter; and have tried two different routers. should I provide any logs? (something like dmesg...)

Comment: I don't think anything can be improved at the OS level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree entirely with my colleague @Pilot6. I doubt there is anything that can be done in Ubuntu. I do believe, however, that much can be done with the wireless access point settings.

Your wireless may be dropping because the channel to which it was connected has suddenly changed.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

Your wireless may be dropping because there are two wireless access points with the same name and password. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Comment: Did all that you said. Problem not solved; but thanks I will use a usb adapter instead.