# Internet drastically slower on Ubuntu than on Windows

Tags: networking, wireless

I am very new into the Ubuntu community, I made the switch two days ago and I'm still getting used to everything. However one of the first things I noticed is that since I've been using Ubuntu, my Internet (Wifi) is significally slower than it was on Windows until wednesday.
obviously I searched the problem before here and I saw several ideas, like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow)
which I all tried, but nothing seemed to work.
I'm not sure which information are relevant but if you need to know more, just ask and I will look it up for you.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I discovered that at least a partial problem seems to be the Wifi Repeater I am using, which is the TP-Link TL-WA854RE Wireless extender. Still not sure about what exactly is causing the issue here and/or how I could fix it

Comment: Please consider these suggestions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453583/intel-ax201-wifi-adapter-disconnecting-frequently/1453593#1453593 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: How have you measured it? something like speedtest.net? or it just feels slower? or something else? Can you also test the speed with a cable connection?

Comment: @user253751 I used the google, vodafone and ookla speedtests and all came to similiar results. I am pretty sure the problem is connected to the wifi repeater that I am using (see edit in post) but that doesn't answer my question on how to solve it